# How to detect a complex QR code using ZXing?

Tags: android, qr-code, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner

Our team is coding an Android QR code scanner app using ZXing 3.4.0 library and we need to scan rather complex QR code like below. We've been testing and found that the scanning is not stable sometimes it could scan the QR code sometimes it can't.

My question is how to optimize the scanning to ensure fast and stable outcome? Should I turn on TRY_HARDER? Should I use Binarizer? If so, which type - GlobalHistogramBinarizer or HybridBinarizer? Should I scan the QR closer to the phone (enlarging the QR code in the camera view)? Anything else I should do?

[image]

Comment: Honestly, your QR code is too dense. It doesn't fit well if you are using consumer mobile camera for reading. There are lots of articles online regarding size and pixel (module) density for QR code.

Comment: Yeah, I know but we have no other choice. But it happens that one app could really scan our QR codes very well, which is https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tw.mobileapp.qrcode.banner and I'm not sure if they are using ZXing or some other library.